# Proof Verification: Showing that these two product metrics are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I am working on this problem from Simmons' "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis" (Problem 10-6).

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be a finite class of metric spaces with metrics $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$. If $X = X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n$, and $d$ and $\bar{d}$ are metrics defined as follows:

$$d(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\}) = \max d_i(x_i, y_i)$$
$$\bar{d}(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i(x_i, y_i)$$

then show that the two metric spaces $(X, d)$ and $(X, \bar{d})$ have precisely the same open sets.

(Here, $\{x_i\}$ denotes an n-tuple from $X = X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n$)

Here is my approach:

I know a theorem that two metrics are equivalent iff. every open ball in the first metric contains an open ball from the second metric (centred at the same point) and vice-versa.

So, let $B_d(\{x_i\}, r)$ be and open ball in $(X, d)$. Here, $B_d(p, r)$ denotes an open ball with respect to metric $d$, centered at p and with radius $r$. Let $\{y_i\} \in B_d(\{x_i\}, r)$, now, we wish to show that $\{y_i\} \in B_{\bar{d}}(\{x_i\}, s)$ for some $s > 0$ (possibly a function of $r$?).

Now, $$\{y_i\} \in B_d(\{x_i\}, r) \implies \max d_i(x_i, y_i) < r \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i(x_i, y_i) < nr \\ \implies \{y_i\} \in B_{\bar{d}}(\{x_i\}, nr)$$

Similarly, let $\{y_i\} \in B_{\bar{d}}(\{x_i\}, r)$, then,

$$\{y_i\} \in B_{\bar{d}}(\{x_i\}, r) \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i(x_i, y_i) < r \implies \max d_i(x_i, y_i) < r \\ \implies \{y_i\} \in B_d(\{x_i\}, r)$$

So, we conclude that the metrics $d$ and $\bar{d}$ are equivalent.

I would really appreciate some comments/correction on this proof. In particular, I would like to know that when we show an open ball (with respect to first metric) having radius $r$ is contained in an open ball (with respect to second metric) having radius $s$, then, can $s$ be a function of $r$ or must it be constant depending only on the center? At this point I haven't yet studied homeomorphisms or Lipschitz equivalence of norms, so please avoid using those concepts.

Comment: For the first part  you wish to show that there exists $s>0$ such that $B_d(x,s)\subset B_{\bar d}(x,r)$  when $r>0.$ So you should say "Let $s= r/n,$,,, (etc.)"...BTW Metrics that generate the same topology are called equivalent.  If  for metrics $ d,e$ there exists positive $K, L$ such that $K e(x,y)\leq d(x,y)\leq Le(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ then $d,e$ are called uniformly  equivalent . Uniform equivalence is sufficient, but not necessary, for $d,e$ to be equivalent . In the Q, let $e=\bar d$ and $K=1$ and $L=n. $

Comment: In general $s$ may depend on both $r$ and on the center of the open ball. For example :The function $f(x)=\tan x$ is a homeomorphism from $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$  to $\Bbb R.$ So on $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$ we can take the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$  or the equivalent metric $e(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for the reply. I understand the first part of your comment. Since, the theorem states that two metric are equivalent if "every open ball in the first metric _contains_ an open ball from the second metric" and not "every open ball in the first metric _is contained_ by an open ball in the second metric". So, we should first show that $B_d(x, s) \subset B_{\bar{d}}(x, r)$ by choosing $s = r/n$. Now, regarding uniform equivalence, is it not necessary because it is derived from uniform equivalence of norms and not every metric is induced by a norm?

Comment: Uniform equivalence of metrics is as I stated. It also happens to be true that  any two norms on $\Bbb R^n$ or on $\Bbb C^n$ are uniformly equivalent as metrics, for a  finite $n.$....  It is easy to show that uniformly equivalent metrics are equivalent using the method of your answer to the Q. If you had this result already then you could apply it to $d$ and $\bar d$ as in my 1st comment.....BTW. If $d,e$ are unformly equivalent and $d$ is bounded then (obviously) $e$ is bounded...BTW. Any  metric $d$ is equivalent to the bounded metric $e(x,y)=\min (1,d(x,y)).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_1 \le n \|x\|_\infty $.

Hence 
$ {d}(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\})  \le \bar{d}(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\})  \le n{d}(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\}) $

Just to clarify, if $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$ then
$d(x,y) = \|(d_1(x_1,y_1),...,d_n(x_n,y_n))\|_\infty$ and
$\bar{d}(x,y) = \|(d_1(x_1,y_1),...,d_n(x_n,y_n))\|_1$.

Comment: But the problem never stated that the metrics $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$ are induced by norms. So, I don't understand how that inequality for sup norm and 1-norm is useful in this case.

Comment: The metrics can be written as a norm of the vector with components $d_i ( x_i , y_i ) $.

Comment: I am not stating that the metric is a norm, but in the case they can be written as a norm of a vector of metrics so we can use the norm equivalence to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Now it makes sense. You applied that norm inequality on the vector $(d_1(x_1, y_1), d_2(x_2, y_2), \dots, d_n(x_n, y_n))$, and then used uniform equivalence, right?

Comment: @feynhat: That is correct.